# Refresh WebApp occasionally returns Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8

I have a very basic webapp that every two minutes runs a stored procedure and presents the data in a table format.

It works great except right at shift change.

There are other processes running on the same data during these times but not enough to cause a timeout. In fact, I have the sp setup to just return blank values for those times but the issue remains.

Not every time but once every couple of days instead of refreshing data, IE will spit out an 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage' and remain in that state until refreshed (F5).

Nothing in the logs, SQL profiler shows the sp running without issue.  The sp executes in under 1 second.

**Controller**

```
       public ActionResult Desktop()
    {

        Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "120");

        try
        {
            var dResults = db.VDMDisplayReporting();
            return View(dResults.ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Fail", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

<table width="20%" class="checkerboard" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0">
    <tr>       
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:Silver">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MachineId)
            </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: @item.YieldColor">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Yield) 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:  @item.UptimeColor")>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Uptime) 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: @item.CycleColor">
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cycle)
            </td>
        </tr>                        
    </tr>
</table>

}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what IE reports error-wise?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related problem: [IE doesn't follow redirect, gives "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948128/ie-doesnt-follow-redirect-gives-internet-explorer-cannot-display-the-webpage)

RedirectToAction return responce with not full location url like /Home/Action
But IE prefer full url http://domain.com/Home/Action

Try this.